# How to use a LaTeX alternative to {} in order to import R/exams cloze questions to Moodle with LaTeX code?

Tags: r, latex, moodle, r-exams

We are using the marvelous `exams` package to produce items to be imported to Moodle. Although we noticed that using LaTeX code (i.e. {}) creates conflict with the Moodle code when importing questions. As so, we would like to know alternatives to use all LaTeX functionalities within Moodle. E.g. the

$H_0: \mu_{males}=\mu_{females}$ won't be imported due to the "{}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate this problem. I just tested the import in my Moodle system and this looks ok:

[image: Moodle screenshot]

The content of my `import.Rmd` exercise is included below.

Possibly you have some extra filters enabled that prevent importing such content into your Moodle system?

[We've previously seen problems with rendering certain R/exams exercises in Moodle when the tidy XHTML filter was activated. However, these problems occured at the rendering stage not at the import stage (and then also just in very specific settings). So I suspect that your problem is not caused by this filter.]

```
Question
========
Is it possible to import questions with LaTeX code like
`$H_0: \mu_{males}=\mu_{females}$`
that should be rendered like
$H_0: \mu_{males}=\mu_{females}$?

Answerlist
----------
* Yes
* No

Meta-information
================
exname: LaTeX import
extype: schoice
exsolution: 10
```

#### Update

Prompted by the answer from Beatriz I was able to replicate the error. It only occurs if curly brackets are used in the answer alternatives for single-choice or multiple-choice elements of cloze questions. The reason is that Moodle's syntax for embedded answers relies on curly brackets (`{1:MULTICHOICE:...}`) and hence closing curly brackets have to be escaped. This has been implemented in version 2.4-0 of R/exams.

[image: Moodle screenshot]

The corresponding content of `hypothesis.Rmd` is:

```
Question
========
Consider a numeric response `outcome` and is a binary factor `gender`
with levels `male` and `female`. What is the alternative hypothesis
used in `t.test(outcome ~ gender)`?

Answerlist
----------
* $\mu_{male} \neq \mu_{female}$
* $\mu_{male} \leq \mu_{female}$
* $\mu_{male} \geq \mu_{female}$

Meta-information
================
exname: Alternative hypothesis
extype: cloze
exclozetype: schoice
exsolution: 100
```

Comment: To solve this issue we removed all the "{}" from the rmd.

Comment: If you have some sort of IT services or tech support for Moodle, I would recommend to contact them about this. Maybe they can say where this comes from for you - because it isn't a problem for me. Alternatively, asking in a Moodle-specific forum might help because this isn't related to R/exams, it's just about Moodle.

Comment: I tried to use the `converter = "pandoc-mathjax"`however it might allow importing without errors, the LaTeX code does not appear correctly formatted. :(

Comment: @Sinval I think I found the bug that has troubling you, see my update above. The lesson learned from this should be: Please post a minimal reproducible example for the problems you have. In case of R/exams this should either use a built-in exercise or you should supply a simplified version of the exercise (like the ones I posted) that produce the error. Otherwise we can only guess what you tried - and evidently sometimes we guess wrongly!

Comment: Thank you, @Achim. I will try it in our next exams season (Jully). :)

Comment: If you do, please remember to accept the answer so that the problem appears as resolved here on StackOverflow, thanks.

Comment: I tested it, it is working with the latest devel version (i.e. 2.4-0 of R/exams on R-Forge). Great!

Comment: I think the problem still persists in 2.4-0 if Latex code is in the exsolution field of a exclozetype: string|string question.

Comment: Yes, this may well be, I'll check. And just to be sure I understand correctly: You want the participants to enter verbatim LaTeX code in a string answer field?

Comment: I think the problem should be fixed now in the devel version (2.4-0) available from R-Forge (r1917). It would be great if you could test it on your exercise. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but when I only if I include {} in the answerlist options with something of length greater than 1, for example \sqrt{25} o t_{25}. \sqrt 2 and t_2, works ok. It works if it is included in question text.